# Scala - How do I modify an input array passed to a method by reference?

Tags: arrays, scala, pass-by-reference

**Problem Statement**

I will try to elaborate the case by means of a scenario. Lets take this question for instance.

Link to question: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-element/

> Given an array `nums` and a value `target`, remove all instances of
>   that value in-place and return the new length.
>
> *Do not allocate extra space for another array, you must do this by modifying the input array in-place with O(1) extra memory.*
>
> Example: Given `nums = [0,1,2,2,3,0,4,2]`, `target = 2`; the `output =
>   5` (number of elements not equal to target) and modify the array to
>   `[0,1,3,0,4]`
>
> The order of elements can be changed. It doesn't matter what you leave
>   beyond the new length.

**My Approach**

Step-1: Identify all the elements which are equal to the given target and move them to right hand side of the array while maintaining a counter.

Step-2: Drop all the elements from right.

Step-3: `return (n - counter)`, where n is the array length and counter is the number of elements equal to target.

Below is the implementation of the same:

```
object RemoveElement {
  // Link to question: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-element/
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    var nums = Array(3,2,2,3)
    val target = 3
    val result = removeElement(nums, target)
    // nums = nums.dropRight(_.equals(target)) // POINT 1
    println(s"Result: ${result}, Modified Array: [${nums.mkString(", ")}]")
  }

  def removeElement(nums: Array[Int], target: Int): Int = {
    val n = nums.length
    var left, counter = 0
    var right = n - 1

    while(left < right){
      if(nums(left) != target){
        left += 1
      }
      else {
        // Find position of the elements which is not equal to target
        if(nums(right) == target){
          counter += 1
          right -= 1
        }
        else{
          // Swap the elements
          counter += 1
          val temp = nums(left)
          nums(left) = nums(right)
          nums(right) = temp
          left += 1
          right -= 1
        }
      } 
    }
    // nums.dropWhile(_.equals(target))  // POINT 2
    // nums = nums.dropRight(_.equals(target))  // POINT 3
    return (n - counter)
  }
}
```

POINT - 1: Makes absolute sense as the array `nums` is in the scope of main method, therefore, the statement would work as charm.

POINT - 2: These lines has no impact to the array `nums`.

POINT - 3: Gives error. I understand that the input argument (array `nums`) is of type `val` (i.e. passed by reference, and hence immutable within the scope of the method `removeElement`).

If I had an option of creating a new array, there wouldn't be any issue. But if I am required to return the modified array by adding/removing the elements (like in this question) to the calling method, how do I achieve that in Scala?

To make the case more generic, what is the way by which we can modify the input collections (passed as arguments) in Scala methods?

**P.S.:** If I do not remove elements from the input array itself, LeetCode fails my submission with below message:

[image]

Comment: Too many things here. First, those problems are very imperative, they may be good for learning languages like **Python** , **Java** or **C/C++**, but not **Scala** which is a more declarative language, even if **Scala**allows you to be imperative when you need to _(for example when performance matters)_ that is not common, so if you are going to learn a language, it would be good to learn it idiomatically.

Comment: Second, I think the problem is a bit misleading, AFAIK an **Array** is a reserved amount of memory with a fixed size, you can not really remove elements from it, you may fill the extra spaces with zeroes or `null`. But they must remain there. And this is not only true for **Scala** but for any **JVM** language. Also, I would expect the same in any native language _(e.g. **C/C++** or **Python**)_ but maybe there are tricks using `malloc` to trim the memory.

Comment: True! But Scala provides many functional capabilities and handles things internally for us. `drop`/`dropRight` are one of those methods which do the dirty work for us. I just want to figure out how to go about it in situation described in above question, if we must.

Comment: Almost all methods in the **collections** library return modified copies, instead of modifying the original collection. Some _mutable_ collections provide modify in place methods, but again those are usually reserved for special cases. And in the case of an **Array** such `dropInPlace` doesn't exist _(probably for what I said in my second comment)_. Finally, even when performance matters, it is weird to expose a public method that modifies its input.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I modify an input array passed to a method by reference?

Scala does not support pass-by-reference. The default is pass-by-value (or more precisely, a special case of pass-by-value which is sometimes known as call-by-object, call-by-sharing, or call-by-object-sharing). Scala also supports call-by-name.

So, you simply *cannot* pass an array to a method by reference in Scala. You will have to use another language which supports pass-by-reference such as C# (with the `ref` keyword) or C++. (Note that Java also doesn't support pass-by-reference.)

Comment: thank you for your response. What should I do in my case to modify (remove elements from) the input array? I am able to swap the elements though.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
object Solution {
    def removeElement(nums: Array[Int], `val`: Int): Int = {
      var p: Int = 0
      nums.foreach(v => {
        if (v != `val`) {
          nums(p) = v
          p += 1
        }
      })
      p
    }
}
```